# Getting error in implementing Keras in R for image classification

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to create a deep learning model for classifying an image based on 5 variables (R,G,B,NIR,NDVI). The training samples are in a point shapefile with all 6 variables including the class column. I am using Keras library in R for creating the model.

```
library(keras)
install_keras()
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(gpu=T)
library(magrittr)
library("tidyverse")
library(reticulate)

#Training samples 
trainingSamples <- readOGR("Q:/2.0.Projects/Fiber/Satellite/Field Validation/Cerato training samples/Training samples/AllSamples.shp")
data.df <- as.data.frame(trainingSamples)
train.df <- data.df[c(3:7,12)] #3-7 variables are R,G,B,NIR and NDVI and 12th variable is corresponding class.

#converting class variable into numeric (Classes are in characters)
train.df$Class <- as.numeric(train.df$Class)
```

## normalizing the data

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  train.df[,i] <- (train.df[,i]-min(train.df[,i]))/(max(train.df[,i])-min(train.df[,i]))
}
```

## Split data - Determine sample size

```
  ind <- sample(2, nrow(train.df), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.80, 0.20))
    training <- train.df[ind==1, 1:5]
    test <- train.df[ind==2, 1:5]

# Split the class attribute
    traintarget <- train.df[ind==1, 6]
    testtarget <- train.df[ind==2, 6]
```

## one hot encoding

```
trainlabels <- to_categorical(traintarget)
testlabels <- to_categorical(testtarget)
```

## creating the model

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dense(units=5, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(5)) %>%
  layer_dense(units=1, activation = 'softmax')

summary(model)

#Compiling the model to configure the learning process
model %>%
  compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam',
          metrics = 'accuracy')

#Fit model
mymodel <- model %>%
  fit(training, 
      trainlabels,
      epoch=100,
      batch_size=32,
      validation_split=0.2)
```

## Error

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fit’ for signature ‘"keras.engine.sequential.Sequential", "matrix"’
```

I have tried converting dataframe to matrix then applying dimnames as NULL, still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem until I realized that I was using two scripts in the same R session. Because of that, I had a whole bunch (30+) of other libraries loaded. Therefore, I restarted the R session and only loaded the *keras* library-- the problem disappeared. So it looks like one of the other libraries caused the conflict with the fit function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did remove all other libraries other than keras. Unfortunately still showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by following steps:
1. Removing whole bunch of unused libraries for this exercise (as suggested by @hopethishelps)

2. Converting the dataframe into matrix
3. Tweaking the model input_shape and the output layer as follows

   model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%

## Input layers

layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "relu", input_shape = ncol(training)) %>%

## Hidden layer

layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "relu") %>%

## Output layer

layer_dense(units = ncol(trainlabels), activation = "softmax")